Generalization error as U shape curve with respect to model complexity (bias variance tradeoff))
Is there any work mathematical rigorously prove that the generalization error for certain learning problems exhibits U shape curve with respect to model complexity (bias variance tradeoff)? Any reference

Indeed the usual empirical risk minimization principle cannot directly show the tradeoff's U shape curve, but if you follow its regularized version aka structural risk minimization (SRM) then it'll be much more intuitive for the U shape curve.

Commonly in machine learning, a generalized model must be selected from a finite data set, with the consequent problem of overfitting – the model becoming too strongly tailored to the particularities of the training set and generalizing poorly to new data. The SRM principle addresses this problem by balancing the model's complexity against its success at fitting the training data.

We know $\text{generalization error=bias^2+variance+irreducible error}$, in Shalev-Shwartz et al's Understanding Machine Learning, they showed the approximation error ($\text{bias^2+irreducible error}$) is inversely related to model complexity which is defined as the size of the hypothesis class.

The approximation error does not depend on the sample size and is
determined by the hypothesis class chosen. Enlarging the hypothesis class
can decrease the approximation error.

While the estimation error ($\text{variance}$) increases with model complexity due to an important uniform convergence property of any learnable hypothesis class.

The quality of this estimation depends on the training set size and on the size, or complexity, of the hypothesis class. As we have shown, for a finite hypothesis class, $\epsilon_{est}$ increases (logarithmically) with $|\mathcal{H}|$ and decreases with $m$ (sample size).

Since one error is inversely related to model complexity while the other error is logarithmically related to model complexity, you've now rigorously proved the U shape curve.

That only gives an upper bound (depends logarithmically with |H| , etc.), not the generalization error itself

Add only it only assume H is finite, it is not useful for neural networks.

See my above answer already explained "approximation error (bias^2+irreducible error
) +  estimation error (variance) = generalization error", and approximation error is inversely related to model complexity which you seem ok, and estimation error increases with model complexity as bounded up by log|H|. Note in PAC theory, if H is infinite like neural networks, its |H|=its VC-dimension ∝O(number of weights and biases) which is usually finite with a usually further regularized ANN. The section in that book here simply hasn't introduced vc-dimension yet, for PAC vc-dimension is key for ANNs.

Ok，so does the approximation error itself inversely depend on model complexity, not the bound? I didn't see mathematical statement about this in the book. Can you show where it rigorously states this?

Good. Once you ok'ed estimation error part, the approximation error part should be straightforward since this is a textbook overfit case where noise in training data are approximated perfectly asymptotically, say, by a high order polynomial class H that has high complexity (vc-dimension), also my answer quoted: Enlarging the hypothesis class can decrease the approximation error. If you want more rigor you can invoke universal function approximation of ANNs or polynomials. So this inverse relation 'proves' the rough U-shape of generalization error ∝ (inverse(|H|)+log|H|). Hope this clarifies.
